# Consider $\mathbb{N}$ and let $S= \{A\subset \mathbb{N}|A \text{ contains some prime number}\}$. Find $\tau(S)$

Tags: general-topology

I have the following excercise:

Consider $\mathbb{N}$ and let $S:= \{A\subset \mathbb{N}|A\text{ contains some prime number}\}$ . Find $\tau(S)$, the coarsest topology over $\mathbb{N}$ that contains $S$.

I know that $ \tau(S)=\tau_\mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B}= \{A\subset \mathbb{N}|A \text{ can be written as a finite intersection of elements in } S\}$.

So this means that the elements in $\tau_\mathcal{B}$ are unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$.

I would like to know if a more detailed description can be given.

Comment: You did not quantify $p$, so it is ambiguous.  Is it 
$$
S:= \{A\subset \mathbb{N}| \exists p, p\text{ is a prime number and }p\in A\}
$$

Comment: Yes, it is as you described it @GEdgar . I've already edited the question

Comment: At first look it seems to me like every set is going to be open in this topology. I'd try to prove that, and even if it's wrong trying to prove it might give you a better idea of which sets *are* open.

Comment: It seems this topology is the trivial one. If $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary then... If there's some prime $p\in A$, $A$ is open and we're done. If not, consider $U=A\cup\{p\}$ and $V=A\cup\{q\}$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes. We have $U\cap V=A$ is open.

Comment: Take any set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$. If $A$ contains a prime, then it is in $S$ and then it is in $\tau(S)$. If $A$ only contains composite numbers, then let $p,q$ be two different primes. Then $A\cup\{p\}$ and $A\cup\{q\}$ are both in $S$. Therefore, $A=(A\cup\{p\})\cap(A\cup\{q\})$ is in $\tau(S)$. Therefore, $\tau(A)=P(\mathbb{N})$ is the discrete topology.